# After fadeOut and fadeIn Sliders not displaying items properly

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I am trying to fadeOut schedule slider and fadeIn gallery slider. On fadeOut 1st. gallery slider fades in but does not change Image or slides and after some Intervals slider stops showing item/items.
One strange thing I noticed, If I change browser size (assume:on gallery slider), slider starts working fine but schedule slider stops showing item/items. I am not understanding what might cause this kind of problem, I have searched and tried different approaches but couldn't find any luck.

If any one experienced this kind of problem please help me.
Here is the script.

```
        var current = "schedule";
    setInterval(function ()
    {
        if(current=="schedule")
        {
            current = "gallery";

        }
    else if(current=="gallery")
    {
            current = "schedule";
        }
         $(".mydiv").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#" + current).fadeIn("fast");


    },5000);
```

Comment: current is never being set to gallery from the source code provided because current is being set to schedule every time. Post more code

Comment: Its set to schedule and checked, If current== schedule which it is, current is set to gallery. mydiv is set as class for both sliders.